# how to allow nullable for an enum field in mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, enums

I'm trying to create a new object in MongoDB using **mongoose**.

Here is my mongoose schema:

```js
const UsersSchema = new Schema<BaseUser>(
    {
        email: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            index: true,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        someKey: {
            type: Schema.Types.String,
            default: null,
            required: false,
            enum: Object.values(SomeEnumObj),
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

enum SomeEnumObj = {
 TEST = "TEST",
}
```

When I'm trying to create a new user using:

```js
model.create({
 email: 'some@email.com',
}).exec()
```

The following error throws:

```
users validation failed: someKey: `null` is not a valid enum value for path `someKey`.,
```

I was able to fix this by setting:

```js
enum: [...Object.values(SomeEnumObj), null]
```

But I was wondering if there is a better or more right way of doing this as my solution feels a little hacky, and I expect that if I set the default to null, the validator will allow this to be null.

Comment: Can't you include the null as a value in the `SomeEnumObj`? --> `SomeEnumObj = { TEST: "TEST", _null: null }`

Comment: mmmm I've thinked about that. but i use the enums also as validators, so when editing a user, someKey won't be allowed to be null...

i just realized that this is a pretty bad practice, so ill just add the null to the enum / disallow value to be nullable...

Answer (score 7):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3044) I also didn't find any proper solution as this is my problem too. I believe there is no need to add null as the **default value** `(default: null)` to fix the problem.

Just add this to your schema:

```js
Object.values(SomeEnumObj).concat([null])
```

Your schema :

```js
...

someKey: {
  type: Schema.Types.String,
  enum: Object.values(SomeEnumObj).concat([null]),
}

...
```

Comment: it didn't work for me with just `nullable:true` i had to add `.concat([null]),`

Comment: `nullable: true` is useless

Comment: Huge thanks, one quick change because of TypeScript complaining:

someKey: { type: String, enum: [...[null], ...Object.values(SomeEnumObj)], default: null }

Answer (score 0):

Using `undefined` rather than `null` worked for me:

```
        someKey: {
            type: String,
            default: undefined,
            required: false,
            enum: SomeEnumObj,
        }
```

Comment: Just remember that there's a significant semantic difference between `undefined` and `null`, just like there's a difference between `0` and `""`